# Selecting Multiple Columns by Name without having to Type each name

Tags: r, select, multiple-columns, names

How do I select multiple columns by name without having to type out each name.

For example I have the following code:

```
CTDB[, c(
"ENJOY_TV_RADIO_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_FMLY_CLOSE_FRND_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_HOBBIES_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_FAV_MEAL_CHILD",
"ENJOY_SHOWER_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_SCENT_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_PPL_SMILE_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_LOOK_SMART_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_READ_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_FAV_DRINK_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_SMALL_THINGS_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_LANDSCAPE_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_HELP_OTHR_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_PRAISE_CHILD")] <-revalue(as.matrix(CTDB[, c(
"ENJOY_TV_RADIO_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_FMLY_CLOSE_FRND_CHILD",
"ENJOY_HOBBIES_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_FAV_MEAL_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_SHOWER_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_SCENT_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_PPL_SMILE_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_LOOK_SMART_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_READ_CHILD", '
"ENJOY_FAV_DRINK_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_SMALL_THINGS_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_LANDSCAPE_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_HELP_OTHR_CHILD", 
"ENJOY_PRAISE_CHILD")]), c("0"=3, "1"=2, "2"=1, "3"=0))
```

All the columns are in order but instead of selecting by number like below

```
CTDB[,74:87] <-revalue(as.matrix(CTDB[,74:87]), c("0"=3, "1"=2, "2"=1, "3"=0))
```

I would like to select by the name of the column.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean? Why would you not want the numbers?

Comment: Do the columns you want to select all start with `ENJOY_` and end with `CHILD`? And if so, do you want to select all of them?

Comment: @Onyambu I don't want the numbers, because the position of the columns can change in the dataset.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, all the columns start with ENJOY_ and end with CHILD and yes I want to select everything that starts with ENJOY_ and ends with CHILD

Comment: what criterion can you use to identify the columns you need. What do they all have in common?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `grep` or `grepl`

```
CTBD[,grep("^ENJOY.*CHILD$",colnames(CTBD)]
```

or

```
CTBD[,grepl("^ENJOY.*CHILD$",colnames(CTBD)]
```

Comment: I got this error message: Error in grep("ENJOY.*CHILD", x) : object 'x' not found

Comment: Thank you! I got this warning message: "Warning message:
In matrix(value, n, p) :
  data length [49890] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [14]"   Do you know what it means?

Comment: are you trying to create another matrix? you have 14 columns but the datelength that you have cannot be divided into 14 columns

Comment: If `CTBD` is a matrix then you have to use `colnames`, which also works with data frames.

Comment: I still get this message "Warning message:
In matrix(value, n, p) :
  data length [49890] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [14]"

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this as part of a pipe, you can also use `dplyr::select` and its helper functions in two equivalent ways, including one that can avoid regular expressions:

```
CTBD %>% select(matches("^ENJOY.*CHILD$"))
CTBD %>% select(intersect(starts_with("ENJOY"), ends_with("CHILD")))
```